# Generating page listings using bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory called `mydir` which consists of files like this:

```
_Sidebar.md
Jack.md
Amy.md
Robert.md
(Jack) blah blah.md
(Jack) foo bar.md
(Amy) etc etc etc.md
...
```

The `_Sidebar.md` file contains a listing of all the names I care for, like this:

```
* [[Jack]]
* [[Amy]]
* [[Robert]]
```

The idea is: get the contents of `_Sidebar.md`, get the list of names, loop through them and for each name:

- Find all files whose name starts with `(THATNAME)`
- Save the names of these files in `THATNAME.md`

So in the end, `Jack.md` would read like this:

```
(Jack) blah blah.md
(Jack) foo bar.md
```

And I want to do this using a bash script!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
prefixes=($( cat mydir/_Sidebar.md | grep -oP '(?<=\[\[).+(?=\]\])' ))

length=${#prefixes[@]}

for ((i = 0; i != length; i++)); do
  echo "Prefix $i: '${prefixes[i]}'"
  pref=${prefixes[i]}
  pages=$( eval "ls 'mydir/\(*'" )
  echo "$pages"
done
```

The `$prefixes` array correctly identifies the names. The line with `ls` command in it is incomplete for now; as a start, I want it to give me all files that start with `(` but instead I get an error message:

```
ls: cannot access mydir/\(*: No such file or directory
```

But when I run the command `ls mydir/\(*` I do get the correct result. What am I doing wrong here in calling the `ls` command with a dynamic parameter?

Comment: As the filenames contain spaces, putting them together into `$pages`i is no good idea. And putting a * inside `''` prevents the expansion of the wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the list of pages with parenthesis :

```
pages=( "$mydir"/*\(*\)* ) # using glob
printf '%s\n' "${pages[@]}"
```

Then to iterate over pages :

```
for page in "${pages[@]}"; do
    echo "$page"
done
```

### And stop using the evil *eval* =)